# c++ postmessage to internet explorer

Tags: html, c++, ocx

I'm writing an OCX control loaded in internet explorer 8. It used to send alt+(arrow down key ) messages to IE8 web page using postmessage function

```
::PostMessage(hWnd_IE,WM_SYSKEYDOWN,VK_MENU,0);
::PostMessage(hWnd_IE,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_DOWN, 0);
::PostMessage(hWnd_IE,WM_KEYUP,VK_DOWN, 0);
::PostMessage(hWnd_IE,WM_KEYUP,VK_MENU,0);
```

hWnd_IE is found by:

```
hwnd1 = m_hWnd;
while(1)
{
    hwnd0 = ::GetParent(hwnd1);
    ::GetClassName(hwnd0, (LPTSTR)&buf, 100 ); 
    if ( _tcscmp( buf, _T("Internet Explorer_Server") ) == 0 )
    {
        hwnd0 = ::GetParent(hwnd0);
        return hwnd0;
    }

    hwnd1 = hwnd0;
    if(hwnd0 == NULL)
        break;
}
```

I think it can  work. However html web pages only have single key effect(arrow down key),not mutiple key effect(alt+ arrow down key). I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

i resoule this problem by meself,use sendinput function instead.
.postmessage,sendmessage,keybd_event are all no effect.